# How to resolve sticking in "Realm Selection"?

Tags: configuration, realm, selection, azerothcore

When connecting to my new AzerothCore Server with my client, I remain stuck in "Realm Selection" window. It seems that my authserver doesn't allow me to login to the right worldserver.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Problem resolved. Here's the list of verification and modifications i made:

1) Close your WoW client

2) Verify if your worldserver is up. If your server is installed through Docker you can use the command

`docker-compose ps`

3) Verify the "server info" through the AC Console of the worldserver. If your server is isntalled through Docker, you can use the command:

`docker attach azerothcore-wotlk_ac-worldserver_1`

After attached the worldserver console, write

`server info`

4) If everything is fine, the problem is the ip address in the `realmlist` table of the `acore_auth` DataBase. So, install your a Mysql Client of your choice (SequelPro, HeidiSQL or Mysql Workbench are fine)

5) Connect to your mysql database. The default password for mysql is `password`

6) Use this query for setting the correct external ip address of the worldserver:

```sql
USE acore_auth;
SELECT * FROM realmlist;
UPDATE realmlist SET address = 'your_external_ip_address' WHERE name = 'name_of your_worldserver';
```

7) Login to your server with your WoW client

Enjoy and GG!