# Stuck at realm list select

Tags: authentication, realm

I am using the docker image setup described here: https://www.azerothcore.org/acore-docker/

I was able to get the server up and running and work great for myself on my machine.  I'm able to login and play.  I set the client to look to localhost for it's target.  Worked great.

I wanted my wife and daughter to be able to login as well.  I successfully created their accounts, installed the clients, and they are able to login to my server (i.e. the password check is successful).

However, when the see the realm list, and make a selection, they are immediately redirected to the realm list select screen again.

I've found this topic ([How to resolve sticking in "Realm Selection"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852245/how-to-resolve-sticking-in-realm-selection)), which looks like it might help me resolve the issue, but I can't figure out how to open the mysql connection to the right database.

Can anyone help me work through this with a bit more details, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This forum is for coding specific questions and for us to help, we need to see the code you're having difficulty with along with your troubleshooting. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update the question with your code and we'll take a look! Also, what does this have to do with the MongoDB Realm database?

Comment: I'm sorry if I posted this in the wrong spot; I did read the "How to ask a good question" doc.  Where should I ask questions that are extremely basic?  I'm stuck in my understanding to troubleshoot this at a pre-code step, and don't know where to seek help even understanding how the docker image/database interact. Apologies for the lack of clarity, but I'm very new to this.

Comment: Understood. There is quite a bit of information on their git site as well as a [community forum](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/discussions) and other resources. That's a great place to start.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.