# AzerothCore: Unable to log into game server

Tags: azerothcore

I've followed the steps to install Azeroth Core and set up the client.

After creating an account and logging in I see the Realm Selection click AzerothCore and the screen shows "Logging in to game server" before returning to Realm Selection.

I've tried stopping and starting both the authserver and worldserver.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to connect to this server from a different device then the external IP address needs to be updated manually in SQL DB.

The steps for this fix can be found here:
[How to resolve sticking in "Realm Selection"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852245/how-to-resolve-sticking-in-realm-selection?rq=2)